# Why Not Work wear Append Multiple jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form for client code and I want to display a message if the form must be filled all before the form is submitted.

If only one append it to work, but after I add another one is not working.

Is there a solution?

This code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form id='id_form' action='signup.php' method='post'>
  <label for='name'>Your Name:</label>
  <input type='text' id='name' name='name' value=''/>
  <span class='name'></span>
  <br />

  <label for='username'>Username:</label>
  <input type='text' id='username' name='username' value=''/>
  <span class='username'></span>
  <br />

  <input id="test" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
  $('#test').click(function(){

    if ($('#name').val()=='') {
      $('.name').append(' Name is required')
      return false
    }
    else {
      return true
    }

    if ($('#username').val()=='') {
      $('.username').append(' Username is required')
      return false
    }
    else {
      return true
    }
  })

  $('#name').click(function(){
    $('.name').html('')
  })

  $('#username').click(function(){
    $('.username').html('')
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Your first `if` returns true or false, which ends the rest of the processing of your click function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using:

```
return false;
```

In the middle, and it abruptly stops the execution. So what you need to do is, collect all the errors, and at the end, if there are errors, `return false`.

Have an error flag like this:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
  var error = false;

  if ($('#name').val() == '') {
    $('.name').append(' Name is required');
    error = true;
  }

  if ($('#username').val() == '') {
    $('.username').append(' Username is required');
    error = true;
  }

  return !error;
});
```

And please, don't forget the `;` at the end of each statement.

Comment: Hello, I don't normally do this but my question has had 4 views in the 3 hours since it was posted. Would you be able to help with [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063887/black-background-in-full-screen-with-embedded-sketchfab)?