# Black background in full screen with embedded SketchFab

Tags: html, 3d, embed, embedded-resource, embedding

Model URL: https://skfb.ly/KxQr

Browser: Chrome 47.0.2526.111

**Description of problem**

My problem to do with embedding my model in my personal website. I made a simple HTML file to demonstrate the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<iframe width="700" height="500" src="https://sketchfab.com/models/26f4959eb49b4eaa98044e8f053acc2d/embed?autospin=0.1&amp;autostart=1&amp&preload=1&transparent=1&scrollwheel=0&ui_stop=0"
frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen="true" 
webkitallowfullscreen="true" onmousewheel="">
</iframe>
<p style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; margin: 5px; color: #4A4A4A;">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This code shows the model without the background so it blends in with the web page. However when it is full screened the background is just black.

If I use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<iframe width="700" height="500" src="https://sketchfab.com/models/26f4959eb49b4eaa98044e8f053acc2d/embed?autospin=0.1&amp;autostart=1&amp&preload=1&transparent=0&scrollwheel=0&ui_stop=0"
frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen="true" 
webkitallowfullscreen="true" onmousewheel="">
</iframe>
<p style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; margin: 5px; color: #4A4A4A;">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The background of the model no longer blends in with the web page, because `transparent=0`, and when it is full screened the background is white, as it is meant to be.

Is there a way to embed the model so that it blends in with the web page, like it does when `transparent=1`, but when it is full screened it retains either the original background of the model, like it does when `transparent=0` which in this case is white, or it retains the colour of the part of the web page it is in, which in this case is `#E6E6FA`?

**Edit**

What it looks like in fullscreen with `transparent=1`

[image: Black]

What it looks like in fullscreen with `transparent=0` and what I am trying to make it look like with `transparent=1`

[image: White]

Comment: Why are you using `iframes`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It is the code which came when I clicked on the embed link. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Ah... I see... Do they provide any kind of SDK to insert stuff, not using iFrames?

Comment: I don't exactly get that issue: **http://output.jsbin.com/pecukemiza**

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not that I know of and have updated question to show exact problem